# KSQL table from topic with heterogeneous JSON structures

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is there a way to create a table from a topic whilst parsing the heterogeneous JSON data in Kafka? Currently, the topic `source_topic` receives messages in the format similar to below:

```
{
  "x": 1
  "y": {
    "y1": 10,
    "y2": 10
  },
  "z": 1
}
```

I am trying to use the following KSQL query to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
    (EXTRACTJSONFIELD(message, '$.y.y1') INT,
     EXTRACTJSONFIELD(message, '$.y.y2') INT)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='source_topic',
      VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
      KEY='y1'
);
```

But I simply get a syntax error (at 2:22, which I believe is the message parameter). I'm not sure what is going wrong. I was able to do this by creating a stream which then created the table (using the -> parsing method), but I would like to be able to create the table directly.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"x": 1`